# Looking for YA Horror Anthology Title(s) with one story where a mosquito infestation turns fatal and another where water attacks people

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I'm looking for a horror anthology book that is aimed at young adults or older. Not really sure when it was published but I would say before or around the early 2010s.

Among the stories was one with a group of kids that go camping but their camping site has a serious mosquito infestation. Unfortunately, the mosquito problem turns fatal.

Another story has another group of kids that went swimming and there's something strange with the water. Soon, the water (yup, this one is kind of hard to explain) starts attacking one of the kids; I'm pretty sure that kid dies or gets seriously injured to the point of unconsciousness. After the event, one of the kids is at his house when his mom (or someone else) is at the sink and the water starts attacking her.

I read a bunch of horror stories when I was younger so I'm not sure if my memory jumbled these together into one book or if they're part of separate collections.